# ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top level package

Tags: python, path, python-import, importerror

I tried to import settings.py into states.py

The paths looks like this:

```
code/
    base/
        __init__.py
        Settings.py
    states/
        __init__.py
        States.py
```

The import in settings.py is:

```
from ..base.settings import *
```

And then I get the error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

I added the `__init__.py` files because another post said it would work.

I just moved the files into packeges to be more organized.

I tried to do from code.base.settings import *
With `__init__.py` in code and then it gave me the error:
SyntaxError: Missing Parenthese in call to ‘exec’. Did you mean exec(…)?

Last call was in

```
Line 305 exec code in self.locals
```